# Moving the legend in a fieldset lower in the form

Tags: html, css

In a classical form, we have the legend tag on the same line of the top border like showed below.

[image]

The code is:

```
...
<fieldset>
    <legend>Connexion</legend>
    ...
</fieldset>
```

Is it possible to move this legend lower in the formular like showed below?

[image]

Any idea what is the CSS ?

Thanks.

---

**UPDATE**

Below is the result after applying the following CSS:

```
fieldset { 
    position:relative;   
}    

legend { 
    top:20px; 
    position:absolute; 
    font-size:20px; 
    font-weight:bold    
}
```

[image]

How to add more space after the legend 'Connexion' ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You sure can do this with CSS. Without using absolute positioning you end up with a big gap in the fieldset border.

```
fieldset {
    position:relative;  
}   

legend {
    top:50px;
    position:absolute;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:bold   
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I updated my question to show the result. Now I need more space after the legend 'Connexion'. Any idea?

Comment: Change to: fieldset { 
    position:relative; padding-top:30px   
}

Comment: It works with IE, Chrome, Safari but not in Firefox !

Comment: Post your code on jsfiddle.net and I'll take a look. Send me the url.

Comment: I finally succeed with your solution after some css adjustemnts. Thanks.